# pymysql error attempting to run query : sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, pymysql

I am running a query using `pymysql` and passing a string as a parameter for the `where` clause condition. Code and Error Traceback below:

```
import pandas as pd 

# mysql connection
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
user = 'user'
pwd = 'xxxxx'
host =  'x.com'
port = 3306
database = 'dbname'

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(user,pwd,host,database))

con = engine.connect()

c = 'Phoenix, AZ'

query = '''
        select * from schema_name.table1
        where city = {};
        '''.format(c)

df = pd.read_sql(query, con)
```

Traceback:

```
File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 548, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 775, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1156, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 725, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', AZ' at line 2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value needs to be quoted.  It's best to let the database connector do it, to protect against injection attacks:

```
query = '''
        select * from schema_name.table1
        where city = %s;'''

df = pd.read_sql(query, con, params=[c])
```